# Update if record already exists for todays date

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

Is there is an easy way to change the following query to check to see if a record already exists for todays date if it does to update it with the newest count value.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO daily_record (PageID, count)
             VALUES (".$array['page_id'].",".$array['count'].")");
```

The column I want to check is a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field (record_date - part of daily_record table) if a todays date exists for a pageID then an update needs to happen rather than a new insert.

If someone can help that would be amazing!!!

Comment: Is `record_date` in the same table (`daily_record`)?  Do you really mean if a date exists, or do you mean if the date is today? (I'd imagine it exists for yesterday anyway unless you clear out the table)

Comment: Yeah record_date is in daily_record. If date is today, then update. I will still need to keep a historical record of the previous days... Good point... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you build the `daily_record` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_record (
    pageID INT,
    record_date DATE,
    count INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (pageID,record_date),
        INDEX idxPageID (pageID)
)
```

You could then use the command:

```
INSERT INTO daily_record (
    pageID,record_date,`count`
) VALUES (
    1,'2011-03-31',32
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=32;
```

Obviously pageID/record_date/count would be supplied by the calling code.  This effectively creates a record for the pageID/day with the given count, or if a record for the pageID/day already exists, then it sets the count to the supplied value.

Using the DATE column type prevents you getting free timestamping BUT that's not particularly useful for this table - the way you describe it - since you don't care about the hours/minutes/seconds.

The key here is the unique index created by the `PRIMARY KEY...` line.  If it's uniqueness would be violated by an insert then an update on it can occur instead.

Comment: Very clever! that would do it.

Comment: BTW I through in `INDEX idxPageID (pageID)` under the assumption you might want to retrieve records for a particular page, if the number of rows is much larger than the number of pages (eg 1000 rows of data, for 10 pages) this index isn't going to do squat (full table scan anyway) so by all means drop it - it's not required for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can come up with is either use a `select` with `if ... then` to check for the existance ahead of time, or run the `update` statement first, check `@@rowcount` (records affected) and do an `insert` if it comes back with 0)

i.e. No.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit - this is a little more complex than it seemed at first, because of the DATE thing.]
To UPDATE the record you MUST get the count that you want to update, so that requires you to use a SELECT first. But you need to select the records that are only for the current date.

Let's assume that you have done the code to get the current date into $today.

Then as Kendrick said,

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from daily_record where PageID=\'$array['page_id']\' and date_field BETWEEN '$today'.' 00:00:00' AND '$today'.' 23:59:59'");

if (!$result)
   { mysql_query("INSERT into daliy_record (PageID,count} VALUES (\'$array['page_id']\',\'$array['count']\')"); }
else
   {mysql_query("UPDATE daily_record (count) VALUES (\'$array['count']\')  where PageID=\'$array['page_id']\' and date_field=\'$result['date_field']\'");}
```